# Encrypting and decrypting JavaScript session variables

Tags: javascript, session, encryption

I am trying to store fairly sensitive information to JavaScript session pairs, and I have tried to implement CryptoJS.  My question is I have written function to encrypt and decrypt but I am concerned that the pass phrase is exposed in the JavaScript coding. I have little experience with encryption/decryption techniques, and I was hoping to get some guidance.  The code I have works as far as I can determine.  Here again, am I approaching this problem correctly?

These are my current encrypt and decrypt functions:

```
function EncryptString(Message){
    var PassPhrase = "secret";
    // Encrypt the Message using AES
    var EncryptedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(Message, PassPhrase);
    return EncryptedPassword;
}

function DecryptString(EncryptedPassword){
    var PassPhrase = "secret";
    // Decrypt the Message using AES
    var DecryptedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(EncryptedPassword, PassPhrase);
    // Convert the DecryptedPassword data to a string
    var DecryptedString = DecryptedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    return DecryptedString;
}
```

Comment: Is this running on the client or server? If it's on the server you could put the passphrase in a file. Although if someone has access to the source code, they'll also be able to access the file.